# Django Custom Tag - Replace more than 3 line breaks with two line breaks

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am attempting to write a django custom tag to replace more than 3 occurrences of a line break (`\n`) with 2 line breaks.

For example, I would like to replace the following

`\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n` or `\n\n\n\n\n` or `\n\n\n` with `\n\n`

Here is my custom tag so far:

```
@register.filter(name='replace_three_linebr')
def replace_three_linebr(value):
    """Replaces all occurrences of GT 2 adjoined line breaks with 2 line breaks from the given string."""
    return value.replace("\n\n\n", "\n\n")
```

Comment: This is a template filter, not a template tag. That said, what is the problem with your filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value.replace("\n\n\n", "\n\n")` snippet does not work like that. Sometimes the best thing you can do is to fire up the REPL and try the statement:

```
>>> value = '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n \n\n\n\n\n \n\n\n \n\n'
>>> value.replace('\n\n\n', '\n\n')
'\n\n\n\n\n\n \n\n\n\n \n\n \n\n'
```

You would have to apply it several times until there is no more than two consecutive breaks:

```
>>> while '\n\n\n' in value:
...    value = value.replace("\n\n\n", "\n\n")
>>> value
'\n\n \n\n \n\n \n\n'
```

I've not profiled it but I guess it is more efficient to use a regular expression:

```
>>> value = '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n \n\n\n\n\n \n\n\n \n\n'
>>> re.sub('\n\n+', '\n\n', value)
'\n\n \n\n \n\n \n\n'
```

Comment: Thanks Paolo, the `re.sub('\n\n+', '\n\n', value)` works jut as I want. Don't forget to import the `import re` to make this work!